# Extracting files from that have been uploaded via SFTP via any windows method

Tags: ssis, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to get access to files that have been uploaded to SFTP via windows explorer without using an FTP client.  Files can be uploaded to the external SFTP address and viewed through a client using my iFTP address, but I need to be able to read the files that have been uploaded through windows explorer.

Is this possible through the command prompt or any integration software like SSIS?  I've been googling for the last hour and can't find anything.

thanks.

Comment: Windows Explorer does not support SFTP (SSH subsystem). Maybe you mean FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL).

Comment: This doesn't seem like an SSIS question... but to answer your question, checkout [Swish FTP](http://www.swish-sftp.org/)

Answer (score -1):

SSIS can solve this problem but only for FTP Connection.

If you need you use SFTP connection then use CozyRoc Integration with SSIS.

CozyRoc is a tool which provides components like SSIS. You can use it within Visual Studio after installation.

You should use **SFTP task** for SFTP connection.

Hope, this could help you out!

Comment: You can check it out on cozyroc.com website.